# Veins No such file or directory error

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am new to Veins, I have followed the series of steps mentioned in the Veins website for installation. Until step 3 is gone well, but at step 4 I have the following issues.

> bash: cd: C:Users Dveins-veins-5a1examplesveins: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You might have used backslash (`\`) characters instead of slash (`/`) characters